# Java Regex validator

Tags: java, regex

I will get a where clause string (only conditions separated with AND/OR operators ) from a REST service request payload. I want to validate the input string using regex. Every individual where condition will contains **Key  operator  Value** format.

I tried up to some extent to achieve that. I am new to REGEX. I wrote some code to validate that. But it's working partially. 
Can someone please suggest the correct REGEX and if possible please explain how it works. This is very helpful.

So my question is: 
Is my REGEX is correct? If Yes why the matches() method returning  **false** for the second and third input strings.

To make it robust as any complex string comes is this regex will handle that? 
Ex:
"(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\") OR (userName eq \"bjensen\" or familyName co \"O'Malley\")"

I am pasting my code snippet.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DummyTester {
    public DummyTester() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        checkRegex("userName eq \"bjensen\"");  // returning Matches True
        checkRegex("(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\")"); // returning matches False
        checkRegex("(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\" AND userName eq \"bjensen\" AND familyName co \"O'Malley\")"); // returning matches False

    }

    static String checkRegex(String tester) {

        String regex ="(\\w[\\w\\d]* \\s*(?:co|eq|gt)\\s* \\\"\\w[\\w\\d\\-\\:\\']*\\\")* ?(?:and|or|AND|OR)?";
        System.out.println("The input rgex  sis : "+regex);
        System.out.println("The input String sis : "+tester);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(tester);
        boolean b = m.matches(); 
        System.out.println("matcher is   : "+ b);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The output for the above code snippet is below.

### Output:

The input rgex  sis : (\w[\w\d]* \s*(?:co|eq|gt)\s* \"\w[\w\d-:\']*\")* ?(?:and|or|AND|OR)?

The input String sis : userName eq "bjensen"

matcher is   : true

The input String sis : (userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley")

matcher is   : false

userName eq "bjensen" and

familyName co "O'Malley"

The input String sis : (userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley" AND userName eq "bjensen" AND familyName co "O'Malley")

matcher is   : false

userName eq "bjensen" and

familyName co "O'Malley" AND

userName eq "bjensen" AND

familyName co "O'Malley"

Thanks, Vijay

Comment: So what is your question? You have posted some examples but haven't explained what the code is supposed to do and what the expected result is. Update your question by clearly explaining your issue.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I updated the post if my question is not clear please let me know.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the code is supposed to do, why is the first valid, what is the purpose of the regex?

Comment: Thanks Joakim, for your continuous response. I updated my question I don't know why the regex(m.matches(0method) is returning true for the first input string.

Comment: *"Is my REGEX is correct?"* Wrong question. The correct question would be *"Is REGEX correct for this?"* and the answer would be **"No"**, because regex cannot *parse* an input like this. --- *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `matches()` function attempts to match the *entire* input regex against your input. Your regex is looking for:

```
[name] [operator] [string] [optional and-or]
```

So, when you have input with *multiple* conditions such as: `"(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\")"`, the regex will not match the entire input but rather just up to the first `and`. But that is not the case with the first test string, namely `"userName eq \"bjensen\""`.

So your code needs to be:

```
    boolean b = m.matches();
    System.out.println("matcher is   : "+ b);
    if (b) { // we have a complete match
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    else {
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
```

But there are a few things that can be improved with your regex. First, the way you have it defined, it would accept as valid input:

> userName eq "bjensen" and

... which has a "dangling" and

This may not be an issue if you assume the input is always correct and you do not need to validate the input. But I propose a change to the regex that will not allow the above string. Also, the character class `\w` is actually equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You are trying to match a name to:

```
\w[\w\d]*
```

But `\w` already includes all the digits. I am guessing that what you are really trying to say is that the first character must be an alpha character and that subsequent characters can be alphanumeric. The way to express that is:

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

Why didn't I include the range `A-Z`? Because I will set the *case-insensitive* flag for the regex with `(?i)`. That also means I can simplify the tests for the different operators by not having to test for both `or` and `OR`.

You are also escaping a lot of characters with backslashes that don't need to be escaped, such as the semicolon.

The final regex is:

```
(?i)               # Turn on case-insensitive flag
[a-z][a-z0-9]*     # Match alpha followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters
\s+                # Match one or more white space characters
(?:co|eq|gt)       # Match "co" or "eq" or "gt"
\s*                # Match 0 or more white space characters
"                  # Match a double quote
[^"]*              # Match 0 or more non-double quote characters
"                  # Match a double quote
(?:                # Start of a non-capturing group
    \s+            # Match one or more white space characters
    (?:and|or)     # Match "and" or "or"
    \s+            # Match one or more white space characters
    [a-z][a-z0-9]* # Match a name as before
    \s+            # Match 1 or more white space characters
    (?:co|eq|gt)   # Match an operator as before
    \s*            # Match 0 or more white space characters
    "[^"]*"        # Match a string as before
)*                 # Optional non-capturing group repeated 0 or more times
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftNLnK/2/)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DummyTester {
    public DummyTester() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        checkRegex("userName eq \"bjensen\"");  // returning Matches True
        checkRegex("(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\")"); // returning matches False
        checkRegex("(userName eq \"bjensen\" and familyName co \"O'Malley\" AND userName eq \"bjensen\" AND familyName co \"O'Malley\")"); // returning matches False

    }

    static String checkRegex(String tester) {

        String regex ="(?i)[a-z][a-z0-9]*\\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\\s*\"[^\"]*\"(?:\\s+(?:and|or)\\s+[a-z][a-z0-9]*\\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\\s*\"[^\"]*\")*";
        System.out.println("The input regex  sis : "+regex);
        System.out.println("The input String sis : "+tester);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(tester);
        boolean b = m.find();
        System.out.println("finder is   : "+ b);
        if (b) {
            String s = m.group();
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
The input regex  sis : (?i)[a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*"(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+[a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*"*)
The input String sis : userName eq "bjensen"
finder is   : true
userName eq "bjensen"
The input regex  sis : (?i)([a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*"(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+[a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*")*)
The input String sis : (userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley")
finder is   : true
userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley"
The input regex  sis : (?i)([a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*"(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+[a-z][a-z0-9]*\s+(?:co|eq|gt)\s*"[^"]*")*)
The input String sis : (userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley" AND userName eq "bjensen" AND familyName co "O'Malley")
finder is   : true
userName eq "bjensen" and familyName co "O'Malley" AND userName eq "bjensen" AND familyName co "O'Malley"
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/LKvWx6)

Comment: Hi Booboo, I am so thankful for your clear explanation.